# How to disable Camera Scanning and Enable only Manually Enter Card in CardIO

Tags: ios, cardio

I have tried more but i cannot able to find any property on Cardio lib. I want to make only Manually enter cardio view. 
I am using CardIOPaymentViewController.
Please let me know what should i need to do for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You find there is property scanning disable

```
[[CardIOPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPaymentDelegate:self scanningEnabled:NO];
```